# How can I add Youtube videos in my website without ads in it?

Tags: html, web, youtube, ads

Even if I add embedded links to my website there still be ADS, right? Any way to enable ad block for all users or any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

[yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) allows you for a given YouTube video (with id `VIDEO_ID`) to get URLs respectively for the video and the audio by using `yt-dlp -g VIDEO_ID`.
So you could play the YouTube video and at the same time play its audio retrieved from a PHP backend for instance. As `yt-dlp` propose links directly to the video content without ads, it would do the trick.